# Preventing development agda from breaking basic standard library usage?

Tags: agda, agda-mode, agda-stdlib

I'm working with the development version of agda, which is now incompatible with the basic standard library version 1.3.

```
wmacmil@w:~/.agda$ agda --version
Agda version 2.6.2-41b6b25
```

A basic failure.agda file,

```
module failure where 

open import Data.String
```

fails:

```
Checking failure (/home/wmacmil/agdaFall2019/constructiveTypeTheoriesNLSem/TT_course/agda_files/failure.agda).
 Checking Data.String (/home/wmacmil/agdaStdLib/agda-stdlib-1.3/src/Data/String.agda).
  Checking Data.String.Base (/home/wmacmil/agdaStdLib/agda-stdlib-1.3/src/Data/String/Base.agda).
   Checking Data.List.Extrema (/home/wmacmil/agdaStdLib/agda-stdlib-1.3/src/Data/List/Extrema.agda).
    Checking Data.List.Membership.Propositional.Properties (/home/wmacmil/agdaStdLib/agda-stdlib-1.3/src/Data/List/Membership/Propositional/Properties.agda).
     Checking Data.List.Membership.Setoid.Properties (/home/wmacmil/agdaStdLib/agda-stdlib-1.3/src/Data/List/Membership/Setoid/Properties.agda).
Killed
```

How can I run two version at once?  And how can I run the experimental version of of the stdlib to avoid this?  Are there any other tricks someone would suggest?

Also, will someone with >1500 reputation make agda-stdlib a tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the description of the standard library, you need to use the `experimental` branch of the library if you are working with the `master` branch of Agda. You can get it by cloning the github repository at `https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib` and doing `git checkout experimental`.

To automatically switch between versions of libraries when you switch Agda versions, you can have multiple `libraries` files as described in the [user manual](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1.1/tools/package-system.html#installing-libraries):

> To be found by Agda a library file has to be listed (with its full path) in a libraries file
>
> AGDA_DIR/libraries-VERSION, or if that doesn’t exist
> AGDA_DIR/libraries
>
> where VERSION is the Agda version (for instance 2.5.1). The AGDA_DIR defaults to ~/.agda on unix-like systems and C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\agda or similar on Windows, and can be overridden by setting the AGDA_DIR environment variable.

Alternatively, you can have a single `libraries` file and check out the right version of the library when you switch Agda versions.